# Using Diesel with different database engines

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I usually do development locally on Postgres, and later switch to MySQL plus SQLite during testing. It's very hard for me to install Diesel for MySQL on Windows, so I'd like to keep using Postgres to not waste time.

Unfortunately, Diesel doesn't generate a database schema, so I need to create it for a target database, which makes easy database switch impossible. Is there any method to generate migrations from models for a certain DB engine? Or maybe any other way to allow easy switching between engines?

Comment: Did you try [`diesel_cli`](https://crates.io/crates/diesel_cli)?

Comment: In diesel_cli I still need to write raw SQL for migrations. I would still need a few different SQLs for a different engines.

Comment: It's not really an ORM like that. It's more like a thin interface on SQL.